# What distribution is my data following?

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution

I have some data that looks like this when plotted:
[image: Plot of number against frequency]

I'd like to be able to work out which distribution it is similar to. My hope was that it was Poisson, but all my attempt to do a Chi Squared test in R result in tiny p-values (perhaps I am doing it wrong).

What is the correct thing to do to find out, and if it is Poisson how do I show it?

Data:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16  17   18   19   20   21 
    217  740  1680 2739 3395 3509 3152 2595 1999 1415 919  610  362  232  118  64   38  22   8    5    1    2
```

Comment: What test are you using and what arguments does it take? My guess is you are feeding your table, listed above, to a function which expects individual values (i.e. 217 0's, 740 1's, etc), which would be a mismatch.

Comment: What kind of data is it ? Often times there may be predictor series which when accounted for render an error process ( a pseudo Y) quite normal.

Comment: You have so many data that you would be lucky indeed to find that they matched any distribution with a simple mathematical formulation.  Perhaps you should consider how to proceed in your analysis without having such a nice result--using approximations or the empirical distribution itself, perhaps.